# How to read tf.exe installtion path usng c#

Tags: .net

I want to read installed tfs file path from my computer using c#. Please suggest me.

Note: If tfs is installed in c:\program files\ms\tools. I have to read this path from application dynamically using c# programming by providing file name like tf.exe.

Comment: you should have that path somewhere in the registry I think, you can get it from there

Answer (score 1):

`TF.exe` is installed as part of VS, or at least the VS shell (if TF Explorer installed standalone).

Therefore once you have the installation path for VS identified you can append the relative path `Common7\IDE\TF.exe`.

One option (this certainly works for a full VS install, I assume so for TF Explorer version of VS shell) is an environment variable:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
VS90COMNTOOLS                  Visual Studio 2008 install folder\Common7\Tools\
VS100COMNTOOLS                 Visual Studio 2010 install folder\Common7\Tools\
VS110COMNTOOLS                 Visual Studio 2012 install folder\Common7\Tools\
```

which is already the right folder (and this environment variable, with the appropriate version number, has been in place since at least VS2002, but VS2008 is the earliest you need for TFS).

(Note these is now a standalone TFS client object model installer, but I suspect that does not include `tf.exe`, if it does then a solution for that case would need to be identified by performing a test intsall on a system that does not have VS or TFS otherwise installed.)